# How to download an entire directory and locate using wget?

Tags: linux, bash, wget

i can download entire folder with following command:

```
wget -r --no-parent http://abc.tamu.edu/projects/tzivi/repository/revisions/2/raw/tzivi/
```

But how can i locate them for example into this folder: `home/web/example`

Comment: This question has nothing to do with regex. Check the man pages of wget to specify the output location.

Answer (score 1):

Try use key `-P`.
Please, note you may need to use command `sudo`.

```sh
wget -r --no-parent http://abc.tamu.edu/projects/tzivi/repository/revisions/2/raw/tzivi/ -P /home/web/example
```